# CLT with random (Binomial) number of summands

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Say we have iid real-valued $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ with expectation $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$ and variance $\sigma^2>0$. Then clearly
$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i-\theta\right)\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{\mathcal{L}}Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2),$$
but what happens if instead of $n$ we have some $Z_n\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$, $p\in(0,1)$, independent of the $X_i$? In order to have everything well-defined, say we consider
$$\sqrt{Z_n+1}\left(\frac{1}{Z_n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{Z_n+1} X_i-\theta\right).$$
Through the tower property for conditional expectation and using 
$$E[1/(Z_n+1)]=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{p(n+1)}=:v_n,$$
we see that
$$E\left[\frac{1}{Z_n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{Z_n+1} X_i\right]=\theta$$
and
$$\mathrm{Var}\left[\frac{1}{Z_n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{Z_n+1} X_i\right]=v_n\cdot\sigma^2,$$
so that I would expect
$$\sqrt{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{Z_n+1}\sum_{i=1}^{Z_n+1} X_i-\theta\right)\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{\mathcal{L}}Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2/p)$$
(since $(n+1)v_n$ converges to $1/p$). But is this correct and how can I justify it?

Comment: A simple approach is to introduce $$Y_n=B_n\cdot(X_n-\theta)$$ where $(B_n)$ is i.i.d. Bernoulli with $P(B_n=1)=p=1-P(B_n=0)$ and independent of $(X_n)$, then apply the usual CLT to $$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nY_k\stackrel{d}{=}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{Z_n}(X_k-\theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

Use characteristic functions. Conditioned on the sequence $\{Z_n\}$ the characteristic function converges to $e^{-t^{2}\sigma ^{2}/2}$ since, by SLLN, $Z_n \to \infty $ a.s..;  you can take expectation and apply Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: "Conditioned on $Z_n$ the characteristic function converges to $e^{-t^{2}}\sigma ^{2}/2$" Huh? "Conditioned on $Z_n$ the characteristic function" does not converge to anything, it is a function of $Z_n$, period.

Comment: @Did Please see if the edited answer is correct. I really meant conditioning on the entire sequence $\{Z_n\}$.

Comment: Indeed, now I can fill in the missing steps (and correct the typo) -- but whether the OP is able to or not, remains to be seen.